# How does a neural network model fractional powers for input variables?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning

From what I understand, a Neural Network is essentially a representation of one or more output in terms of a polynomial equations in a graphical form. That being the case, I fail to understand as to how a Neural Network models fractional powers. For example, if my true natural function is $y = a_1 * {x_1}^{1.45} + a_2 * {x_2}^{2.98} +a_3$, how does the neural network account for the .45 and .98 in the illustrated equation?

Comment: A neural network is a black box. It is hard to explain how it would map those functions. But it *can*, http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap4.html.

Answer (score 1):

The set of polynomials on a closed interval is dense in the set of continuous functions, including your fractional power functions, on a closed interval. Dense means any continuous function can be uniformly approached by a sequence of polynomials. Here approach means approximate to any desired degree of accuracy defined by the maximum of the difference. This is the Stone–Weierstrass theorem which is a generalization of Weierstrass approximation theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem.
Bernstein polynomials gives a specific constructive proof/example of the Weierstrass approximation theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial